# How to add widget to ListView using Bloc Pattern in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently started to dive into Bloc Pattern in flutter, and have learned using this [project](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/fluttertodostutorial).
In this project, there is an adding post feature, so I wanted to implement alike one.
Even I changed Bloc's State via Event, It doesn't add Container Widget to ListView. I tried and search this problem but I can't figure:(

Here are my code below.

Here are Bloc Parts,

```
@immutable
abstract class ContentsState extends Equatable {
  ContentsState([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class ContentsLoading extends ContentsState {
  @override
  String toString() => 'ContentsLoading';
}

class ContentsLoaded extends ContentsState {
  final List<Content> contents;

  ContentsLoaded(this.contents);

  @override
  String toString() => 'ContentsLoaded { contents: $contents }';
}
```

```
@immutable
abstract class ContentsEvent extends Equatable {
  ContentsEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class LoadContents extends ContentsEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'LoadContents';
}

class AddContent extends ContentsEvent {
  final Content content;

  AddContent(this.content) : super([content]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'AddContent { content: $content }';
}
```

```
class ContentsBloc extends Bloc<ContentsEvent, ContentsState> {
  @override
  ContentsState get initialState => ContentsLoading();

  @override
  Stream<ContentsState> mapEventToState(ContentsEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoadContents) {
      yield* _mapLoadContentsToState();
    } else if (event is AddContent) {
      yield* _mapAddContentToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<ContentsState> _mapLoadContentsToState() async* {
    final List<Content> contents = [Content('message')];
    yield ContentsLoaded(contents);
  }

  Stream<ContentsState> _mapAddContentToState(AddContent event) async* {
    if (currentState is ContentsLoaded) {
      final List<Content> updateContents =
          List.from((currentState as ContentsLoaded).contents)
            ..add(event.content);
      // Output update contents
      print('update contents : $updateContents');
      yield ContentsLoaded(updateContents);
    }
  }
}
```

and presentation part,

```
class AddPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      builder: (context) => ContentsBloc()..dispatch(LoadContents()),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AddBody(),
          InputArea(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddBody extends StatelessWidget {
  AddBody({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final contentsBloc = BlocProvider.of<ContentsBloc>(context);

    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: contentsBloc,
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        ContentsState state,
      ) {
        if (state is ContentsLoading) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (state is ContentsLoaded) {
          final contents = state.contents;
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: contents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final content = contents[index];
                return ContentItem(content: content);
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class ContentItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Content content;

  ContentItem({
    Key key,
    this.content,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: Key('__Content__${content.message}__'),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Message Here'),
          Text(content.message.toString()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

~~ in InputArea. There is a TextEditingController and TextField.
onTap: () => contentsBloc.dispatch(AddContent(Content(_controller.text))),
~~
```

Finally, this is my Content class

```
@immutable
class Content extends Equatable {
  final String message;

  Content(this.message);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Content { message: $message }';
}
```

When I run this code, I can see CircleProgressIndicator() -When State is ContentsLoading()- after that, one Container with message text shows up. So far, so good. 
But After I pressed add button and fired AddContent() Event, new content doesn't show up.

Here is a console Log.

```
AddContent { content: Content { message: new message } }
update contents : [Content { message: message }, Content { message: new message }]
```

I want to add Container, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Including excessive amounts of code makes it hard for the people who are trying to help find errors. It is really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the question includes a huge block of code. When this happens, it takes much longer and is much more difficult for other users to search through the code to find the pieces that are relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.

I just add this one line in Bloc's ContentsLoaded class which extends ContentsState.

```dart
class ContentsLoaded extends ContentsState {
  final List<Content> contents;

  // just add this line below.
  ContentsLoaded([this.contents = const []]) : super([contents]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'ContentsLoaded { contents: $contents }';
}
```

Thanks.